# Save a tuple in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, tuples, nsuserdefaults

I'm using a tuple to store something like this.

```
var accessLavels: (hasInventoryAccess: Bool, hasPayrolAccess: Bool)
accessLavels = (hasInventoryAccess: true, hasPayrolAccess: false)
```

Now I want to save it in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(accessLavels, forKey: "AccessLevelKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

But I get the following error.

**Type '(hasInventoryAccess: Bool, hasPayrolAccess: Bool)' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'**

How can I resolve this issue? If its impossible, then any other suggestions to save a tuple is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, calling `synchronize` on `NSUserDefaults` is almost never necessary and calling it "just in case" is not recommended by Apple.

Comment: NSUserDefaults only supports property list types: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you can archive it to create an instance of NSData.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered a similar scenario trying to encode a tuple with `NSCoder`. The way I am solving it is by manually converting the tuple to a `Dictionary`. This is not a great solution as the keys need to be changed in several places if the tuple ever changes.

I had a nested enum in my tuple and gave it a base type (String) from which I converted the raw value. It was a little extra work but thankfully yours is only primitives.

```
# SerializeableTuple.swift

typealias AccessTuple = (hasInventoryAccess: Bool, hasPayrolAccess: Bool)
typealias AccessDictionary = [String: Bool]

let InventoryKey = "hasInventoryAccess"
let PayrollKey = "hasPayrollAccess"

func serializeTuple(tuple: AccessTuple) -> AccessDictionary {
    return [
        InventoryKey : tuple.hasInventoryAccess,
        PayrollKey : tuple.hasPayrolAccess
    ]
}

func deserializeDictionary(dictionary: AccessDictionary) -> AccessTuple {
    return AccessTuple(
        dictionary[InventoryKey] as Bool!,
        dictionary[PayrollKey] as Bool!
    )
}
```

---

```
# Encoding / Decoding

var accessLavels: AccessTuple = (hasInventoryAccess: true, hasPayrolAccess: false)

// Writing to defaults
let accessLevelDictionary = serializeTuple(accessLavels)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(accessLevelDictionary, forKey: "AccessLevelKey")

// Reading from defaults
let accessDic = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("AccessLevelKey") as AccessDictionary
let accessLev = deserializeDictionary(accessDic)
```

Comment: Neat trick! It works well. Although I had to make some slight changes like casting and I think you ought to pass in the `AccessDictionary` to the `deserializeDictionary()` method. I updated your code to reflect the changes. Hope that's okay. Anyway thanks for the aweseome solution. I hope Apple brings support for this in the coming versions of Swift.

Comment: By the way, is there any specific reason for using `setObject` instead of `setValue` and `dictionaryForKey` instead of `objectForKey` in saving and retrieving values from `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: As @LucasHuang notes `setValue` is from `NSKeyValueCoding`. `setValue` uses `id`/`AnyObject` as its type and so doesn’t offer as much type safety at compile time as available. Dictionary is a class (and an instance of Dictionary is an object) and is the most appropriate type-methods. You *could* use the `dataForKey` methods and convert the Dictionary to/from NSData but that is just extra work.

Answer (score 1):

> You can store Bool, Float, Int, Object, Double or URL but not a Tuple. So you have two
>   options, save two only hasPayrolAccess and hasPayrolAccess Bool
>   values:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "hasInventoryAccess")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "hasPayrolAccess")
let hasInventoryAccess  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasInventoryAccess")
println(hasInventoryAccess)

let hasPayrolAccess  = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("hasPayrolAccess")
println(hasPayrolAccess)
```

> Or save it using an Array of Bool:

```
var accessLavels = [true,false]
println(accessLavels)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(accessLavels, forKey: "accessLavels")
if let loadAccessLavels = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("accessLavels") as? [Bool] {
    if let hasInventoryAccess = loadAccessLavels.first {
        println(hasInventoryAccess)
    }
    if let hasPayrolAccess = loadAccessLavels.last {
        println(hasPayrolAccess)
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing as two separate bools works but doesn't take advantage of the power of tuples and separates the data. Storing as an array is a little better because there is only one item stored, but dictionaries are more clear because of the keys (especially for arbitrary tuples).

Answer (score 1):

I had a tuple with 3 values.

The following code was used for saving the tuple. Basically, I created a string from tuple (with components separated by a comma).

```
let defaultsLoad = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if appSingleton.runwayDestShared != nil
{
   // Creating a String from the tuple
   let runwayDestString = appSingleton.runwayDestShared!.0 + "," + appSingleton.runwayDestShared!.1  + "," + appSingleton.runwayDestShared!.2
   defaultsLoad.setObject(runwayDestString, forKey: "RunwayDest")
}
```

To retrieve the tuple, I retrieved the string, broke it into array and used the array to re-create a tuple.

```
let runwayDestString = defaultsLoad.stringForKey("RunwayDest")
if let runwayDestString = runwayDestString
{
    let runwayDestArray = runwayDestString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    appSingleton.runwayDestShared = (runwayDestArray[0],runwayDestArray[1],runwayDestArray[2])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, I don't see any method `-setValue`.
Based on the docs, **NSUserDefaults** is able to save NSString, NSNumber, NSData, NSDictionary, NSArray, NSData and NSDate only. Here is the link: 
[NSUserDefaults Class Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)

So, you are not able to save tuple here. And `-setValue` is from `NSKeyValueCoding`protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts an year old question but still:

```
 let accesLvl : [String:AnyObject] = ["hasInventoryAcces":true, "hasPayrolAccess":false]
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(accesLvl, forKey: "accesLevel")
```

In case you save only bools, `let accesLvl : [String:Bool]` is a better option.

In case I don't get something (I'm fairly new to Swift and programming altogether), what would be the benefit of using a "tuple" over a Dictionary, or even a struct

Comment: Tuple is easier to make and use. No more keys.