# Can't store value of NSMutableArray in NSUserdefault in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

Hi I have a `NSMutablearray` and i am trying to store this array in `NSUserdefault` but I am getting error while storing it.

```
var mutableArray: [(name: String, id: String)] = []

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(mutableArray, forKey: "arrayKey")
```

Cannot convert value of type `'[(name: String, id: String)]`' to expected argument type `'AnyObject?`.

Thanx :)

Comment: You can't store tuples in NSUserDefaults, only objects which are conforming to NSObject.

Comment: Thanks @EricD., Is there alternate ways to resolve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a tuple in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896642/save-a-tuple-in-nsuserdefaults) :)

Comment: you can archive your array into nsdata and save it.
Here is an example in obj-c: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696558/storing-data-to-nsuserdefaults

Comment: @user3820661 this is not NSMutableArray. This is a Swift native array of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a possible solution with some testing in a playground. Basically, we convert the NSMutableArray to a standard array, then to a string, then we neaten up the string, then we store it in NSUserDefaults. Later, we access it from NSUserDefaults, convert it to a standard array, then finally convert it back to the very same NSMutableArray. Here goes the code...

```
var mutarray:NSMutableArray = ["yo", "oy", "pppppp", "01", "long: on", "off"] // just some sample NSMutableArray, replace this with your actual NSMutableArray

var arraytoarray = mutarray as NSArray as! [String] // We convert that NSMutableArray to a standard array of strings

var arraystring = String(arraytoarray) // we convert that standard array to one long string

// then, below, we optimize it and remove characters that will mess up your process later (this might take some tinkering based on your array, but I don't think so)

arraystring = arraystring.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "")
arraystring = arraystring.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[", withString: "")
arraystring = arraystring.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("]", withString: "")
arraystring = arraystring.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")


// then we create an NSUserDefault of that string we've created
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("arraystring", forKey: "stringkey")


// then later on we read that string and create the variable 'name' for it.
if let name = defaults.stringForKey("stringkey") {

print(name)

// we then convert it to an array again
let fullNameArr = name.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)

print(fullNameArr)

// and finally back to an NSMutableArray (if necessary)
var nsMutableArray = NSMutableArray(array: fullNameArr)

} else {
// this is triggered if NSUserDefault was not saved above, in error.
print("nope")
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey @user3820661 let me know if this helps you!!