# How to save an array of Tuple in swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, tuples, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save an array of Tuple in `UserDefaults`. To do this I found on the internet that `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData` can be use to convert the Tuple data into the NSData type. After conversion the tuple data can easily be saved in UserDefaults.
Below is the Tuple array which I want to save

```
[((Color:Color, ID:ID),(DefectType:Type,DefectCode:Code))]
```

but It gives me the below error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue
>   encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1702d47b0

Below is the code I am using

```
            let DATA = ((Color:Color, ID:ID),(DefectType:Type,DefectCode:Code))

            let ArchivedDATA = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [DATA])
            print("ArchivedDATA =",ArchivedDATA)

            defaults.setValue(ArchivedDATA, forKeyPath: "\(self.CodeLabel.text!)")

            if let data = defaults.object(forKey: "\(self.AuditCodeLabel.text!)") as? NSData{

                SavedDefects = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as Data) as? [((Color:UIColor, ID:String),(DefectType:String,DefectCode:String))]
                print("dataUnarchived =",SavedDefects)
            }
```

Please anyone help me to save tuple array into the UserDefaults.If I am going wrong, kindly tell me the proper way to save this.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896642/save-a-tuple-in-nsuserdefaults

Comment: Do your other data types that you use inside your tuple conform to/inherit `NSCoding`? The tuple should be able to be encoded but the data inside the tuple might not.